# multivariate time series anomaly detection

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, time-series, anomaly-detection

I have a time series data looks like the sample data below. so as you can see, i have four events as well as total number of occurrence of each event between different hours. [image: sample data]

after one hour, I will get new number of occurrence of each events so i want to tell whether the number is anomalous for that event based on it's historical level.
I think it's easy if i build four different regressions for each events but in real life i could have many events which makes it less efficient, so I am wondering what's the best way to solve this problem? any models that i should try? I read about KNN but isn't require a classified label while i dont have in my case?

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of time series data, you can try these steps (in this order):

- plot the data to gain intuitive understanding
- use simple z-score anomaly detection
- use rolling mean and rolling std anomaly detection
- ARMA based models
- STL (seasonal decomposition loess)
- LTSM based deep learning model

I assume this TS data is univariate, since it's not clear that the events are related (you did not provide names or context). If they are related you can see how much they are related (correlation and conintegraton) and do some anomaly detection on the correlation.

Comment: hey thx for the reply, these events are not related; for these methods do i run for each events or is it possible to test on all events together then tell if at certain timeframe which event has anomaly ?

Comment: You have following possibilities (1): If features are not related then you will analyze them as independent time series, (2) they are unidirectionally related you will need to use a model with exogenous variables (SARIMAX). And (3) if they are bidirectionaly causal - then you will need VAR model. You first need to determine if they are related: use grangercausalitytests and coint_johansen test for cointegration to see if they are related. See more here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122803/arima-time-series-forecast-auto-arima-with-multiple-exogeneous-variables-in-r

Answer (score 0):

In multivariate time series anomaly detection problems, you have to consider two things:

1. The temporal dependency within each time series. Generally, you can use some prediction methods such as AR, ARMA, ARIMA to predict your time series. On this basis, you can compare its actual value with the predicted value to see whether it is anomalous.
2. The spatial dependency between all time series. At a fixed time point, say *t*, you can use traditional anomaly detection methods such as KNN, GMM, k-means, KDE, PCA based methods to perform anomaly detection.

The most challenging thing is to consider the temporal dependency and spatial dependency **simultaneously**. As far as know, none of the existing traditional machine learning based methods can do this job. In contrast, some deep learning based methods (such as [[1]](https://ojs.aaai.org/index.php/AAAI/article/view/3942)[[2]](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/9507359)) have been proposed to do this job.